# What is the name of this elevated street crossing thing (In Britain?)

Tags: vocabulary, british-english, image-identification

What is the name of this elevated street crossing thing (In Britain?)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a native British English speaker I would call it a *[footbridge](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/footbridge)*

> A bridge designed for pedestrians

although some might call it an *[overpass](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overpass)*

> A passage, roadway, or bridge that crosses above another roadway or
>   thoroughfare.

Comment: Or a [pedestrian bridge](http://www.google.com/images?q=pedestrian+bridge&client=safari&rls=en&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&oq=pedestrian+bridge&gs_l=img.3...33810.33810.0.34328.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1ac.1.24.img..1.0.0.eVMxn1T7qEI)

Comment: In the US, if the purpose of the structure is to separate foot traffic from vehicular traffic it would be called a pedestrian bridge.  Taking a quick look at the Ngram, this phrase is equally shared between US and UK.

Comment: I have also seen it designated as *skyway* in some places, though *footbridge* is by far the commonest term.

Comment: In Britain it is either a 'footbridge', or a 'pedestrian bridge'.

Comment: In the US, an _overpass_ is normally a bridge for motor vehicles to pass over other road or rail traffic. It would introduce confusion to call a pedestrian bridge or footbridge an "overpass". _skyway_ is usually used (in the US) for long or high bridges (for traffic), such as the Sunshine Skyway in Florida. _elevated walkway_ is sometimes used instead of pedestrian bridge or footbridge.